# Error: Invalid PE header machine value with pedump

Tags: linux, pe

I would like to dump the .text section on MS Windows .exe PE files in Ubuntu 14.04.4.

I install pedump, on my Ubuntu system using

```
sudo apt-get install mono-utils
```

When I tried running

```
pedump code /full/path/prefix.exe
```

I got the message

```
Cannot open image  /full/path/prefix.exe
```

When I tried

```
pedump --verify error /full/path/prefix.exe
```

I got

```
Error: Invalid PE header machine value.
```

With another file, I got the following

```
pedump code /full/path/prefix2.exe
Cannot open image  /full/path/prefix2.exe
pedump --verify error /full/path/prefix2.exe
Error: Invalid section alignment 1000
```

Would these problems be due to trying to read MS Windows files on a Ubuntu system?  Is there a better tool I could use to dump the .text section of MS Windows PE files on a Ubuntu system?

Comment: Have you tried `pedump code ./prefix.exe`?

Comment: Yes.  I tried that and the full path name.  However, that is a good point.  I have edited my question to reflect that.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pedump` from Mono utils is a software that does *only* work with .net assemblies. You can't use it to dump standard executables:

```
$ pedump /software/Windows/PortableInstalled/NavPaneCustomizer/Windows\ 7\ Navigation\ Pane\ Customizer.exe |head

COFF Header:
                    Machine: 0x014c
                   Sections: 0x0003
                 Time stamp: 0x4d63c52b
    Pointer to Symbol Table: 0x00000000
           Symbol Count: 0x00000000
       Optional Header Size: 0x00e0
        Characteristics: 0x0102
   ....
```

but

```
$ pedump /software/Windows/PortableInstalled/wxHexEditor/wxHexEditor.exe 
Cannot open image /software/Windows/PortableInstalled/wxHexEditor/wxHexEditor.exe
$ ls -l /software/Windows/PortableInstalled/wxHexEditor/wxHexEditor.exe 
-rw-r--r-- 1 gbl users 1565696 Mai  9  2013 /software/Windows/PortableInstalled/wxHexEditor/wxHexEditor.exe
```

(the ls output shows you it's not an access rights problem)

There is a different software at https://github.com/zed-0xff/pedump that's named `pedump` as well, but these two have nothing to do with each other. You can proably use the online version at http://pedump.me/ if this is a once-only project, and you don't want to go through the hassle of getting a ruby environment working on your system.

If you want to use a local program, `objdump` works fine even for Windows PE executables:

```
$ objdump -d /software/Windows/PortableInstalled/wxHexEditor/wxHexEditor.exe 

/software/Windows/PortableInstalled/wxHexEditor/wxHexEditor.exe:     Dateiformat pei-i386


Disassembly of section UPX0:

00401000 <UPX0>:
  401000:   10 1a                   adc    %bl,(%edx)
  401002:   71 53                   jno    0x401057
  401004:   80 67 17 4b             andb   $0x4b,0x17(%edi)
  401008:   00 3c 3b                add    %bh,(%ebx,%edi,1)
  40100b:   16                      push   %ss
  40100c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  40100e:   ec                      in     (%dx),%al
  40100f:   47                      inc    %edi
  ....
```

(wxHexEditor is probably a bad example, as it's UPX-packed, but i have very few windows programs available on my Linux box right now)